# How to not read the header row while reading csv using Scanner?

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I need to read a csv file in order to do some computations on it using java. I'm using Scanner to read it, but I want to start reading it after the first row (i.e., after the header row), right now I'm just doing: while(inputStream.hasNext()) to read all, what should I do so that the header row is not taken?

Comment: Just get the first line, and then ignore it.  Do that outside of your loop, and it should work.

Comment: Since this is a CSV, why don't you use OpenCSV for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an extra `scan.nextLine();` outside of the reading loop for which you don't use the return value:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\input.txt"));
if (scan.hasNext()) {
    // skip header line
    scan.nextLine();
}

// write contents to output file
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\output.txt");

// read the rest of the file
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    fw.write(scan.nextLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

scan.close();
fw.close();
```

*Edit*: Added code for writing of the non-header content to an output file. Feel free to add some `null` checks on your `scan` and `fw` references if you want.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much! Also, could you tell me how to instead of printing out the output, I can write it to another file like output.csv?

Comment: What I meant was, like I have to find the min, max, average from a column, and write it to output.csv as different columns with Min, Max, Average as the header names of those columns. How to do that?

Comment: Right now, if I just do like: fw.write(min + System.getProperty(",")); fw.write(max + System.getProperty(",")); after the while loop, then I'm getting the following in the output.csv file: 0.03null0.26null (0.03 is the min value and 0.26 the max)

Comment: Don't use [`getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) method in that way if you only need a comma in your string. Do the following instead: `fw.write(min + "," + max + System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Comment: How to get column header names "Min", "Max", "Average" and then shift to new row for the output?

Comment: @JosephWong: You should post a new Stackoverflow question with your new problem.

Comment: I did, nobody answered there!